# Layout/ Dimension Issue with Android Devices on React Native

Tags: react-native

The UI on various Android devices do not look the same. The devices I'm currently using for this example are the Pixel 3a API 30 and Pixel 4 XL API 30 through Android Studio AVD.

```
const deviceWidth =  Dimensions.get('window').width;
const deviceHeight =  Dimensions.get('window').height

<View style = {containers.main_tab}>
    <SafeAreaView style = {{width:'100%', height: deviceHeight * 10/100, borderBottomWidth: 0.4, backgroundColor: top_bg, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', position: 'absolute', elevation: 2,shadowColor: '#000',shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 }, shadowOpacity: 0.3,}}>
    <SafeAreaView style = {{width:'100%', height: '10%', borderBottomWidth: 0.4, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style = {{width: '76%', marginLeft:'12%', marginTop:'5%', height:'5%', alignItems: this.state.language == 1 ? 'flex-start':'flex-end'}}>
    <View style = {{width: deviceWidth*80/100, height: '41%', borderRadius: 10}}>
    <View style = {{width:'100%', height:'20%', marginTop: '7%'}}>
    <View style = {{width: '100%', height: '8%', position:'absolute', top:'81%'}}>
</View>
```

```
    main_tab: {
      width: deviceWidth,
      height: deviceHeight,
      position: 'absolute',
      backgroundColor: '#f2f2f6'
    },
```

The expected outcome here is that all devices would have the same layout and scaling, but that is not the case with Android. I do not seem to have this issue with IOS devices.

Here are the results for the code above.

[Pixel 3a API 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpPiz.jpg)

[Pixel 4 XL API 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnBR6.jpg)

I would appreciate any help, as I've been stuck on this for a while and cannot find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Percentage so frequently because percentage varies from screen size.
6 inch device 5% will be different from 5 inch's 5%. Try using margin: 8, padding: 8 something like this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what margin: 8 actually means? Intuitively I understood percentages to have be more accurate across devices as the percentage is always the same. While if I go with margin: 8, it would different on a device with a height of 700 vs a device with a height of 600 for example. I assume I've completely misunderstood this? I also primarily use deviceHeight and multiply it with the desired fraction. And even when I do that with this component, the issue is still present.

Comment: percentage is the size of the margin as a percentage, relative to the width of the containing block whereas margin: 8 is the size of the margin as a fixed value.
refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom

Comment: Would using fractions of deviceHeight/ deviceWidth as defined above work instead?